# PostgreSQL log warnings: open temporary statistics file, pgstat wait timeout

Tags: linux, postgresql

We frequently get the following warnings with our Postgresql Database

1. LOG: could not open temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/pgstat.tmp": No space left on device
2. WARNING: pgstat wait timeout

When we get the above two warnings, our database connectivity to our website throws a connectivity error and while restarting the Database service then the connectivity looks good for a while.

What could be possible reasons behind this?

I have checked the free space left in the server which is 14 GB.

Comment: Please show: `SELECT version()`, how you installed PostgreSQL, and your OS/distro/version.

Comment: Also the output of the queries `SHOW data_directory;`, `SHOW temp_tablespaces;`, and the "df -h" command on the shell.